# ERROR: syntax error at or near "with" Position: 857

Tags: sql, postgresql, syntax-error

For the query:

```
    select u.id as user_id,
           (a.connected_at is not null) has_two_by_two
    from core_user u
    join core_profile p on u.id = p.user_id
    join core_conversation c on (c.profile1_id = p.id or c.profile2_id = p.id)
    join analytics_connection a on c.id = a.conversation_id
    group by u.id, (a.connected_at is not null)
)
select u.id as user_id,
       date_trunc('month', u.created at time zone 'UTC')::date as month,
       p.community_id,
       p.organization_id,
       p.profile_type_intention,
       (p.basic_account_completed and (p.is_mentor or p.is_entrepreneur)) as profile_is_completed,
       exists(select 1 from core_message where core_message.sender_id = p.id) as has_sent_a_message,
       exists(select 1 from users_having_connected where user_id = u.id) as has_two_by_two
with initiators as (
    exists(select 1 from core_admin_conversation_w_resp where initiator_id = p.id) as has_received_a_response_to_first_message
    from core_profile p
    where p.profile_type_intention is not null
    order by has_received_a_response_to_first_message desc
), responders as (
    select p.id as p_id,
    exists(select 1 from core_admin_conversation_w_resp where responder_id = p.id) as has_received_a_response_to_first_message
    from core_profile p
    where p.profile_type_intention is not null
    order by has_received_a_response_to_first_message desc
), boff as (
    select * from initiators
    union
    select * from responders
)
select distinct p_id from boff
where has_received_a_response_to_first_message = true
from core_user as u
join core_profile p on u.id = p.user_id
where
p.profile_type_intention is not null
```

I get the following: ERROR: syntax error at or near "with" Position: 857

I started out with two separate queries that work independently and I am trying to join them into one query so that users have all the variables of both available.

I am wondering where to start to debug.

Comment: The CTE definition must come *first* - review the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at these lines:

```
...
    group by u.id, (a.connected_at is not null)
)
select u.id as user_id,
...
```

There is most likely a comma missing after the closing parenthesis and you need to assign a name to the following `SELECT`

```
...
    group by u.id, (a.connected_at is not null)
), foo_bar as (
select u.id as user_id,
...
```

Furthermore there seems to be an additional `WITH` before the `initiators as`.